# How to skip first 9 rows of a csv and read the file in Apache Nifi

Tags: csv, etl, apache-nifi

I'm creating a pipeline in NiFi and I have a csv file to be extracted and I want to skip the first 9 rows and read the csv. Need some assistance on how to achieve this in Apache NiFi.

Comment: There is currently not a straightforward approach to this, there is an [open ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-8932) with NiFi to get this functionality implemented. Maybe you can vote for the issue. Until then follow the details provided in the ticket

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea on the regex I can use for this in RepalceText processor. I still can't get it working in NiFi

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SampleRecord processor for this, setting `Sampling Strategy` to `Range Sampling`. Then you can set `Sampling Range` to `1, 11-` if you want the first row as a header, or `10-` if you don't.